# IconItemRenderer with HTML Support

Tags: html, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder

Im currently developing an custom Icon Item Renderer that support HTML in the message fields.

I have two files.

1. view1.mxml - that contains the spak list component
2. htmlRenderer.mxml - the icon item renderer

Codes

htmlRenderer.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer
          xmlns:fx                        = "http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
          xmlns:s                         = "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
          xmlns:mx                        = "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
          autoDrawBackground                          = "true"
          width                           = "100%"
          creationComplete="callLater(renderHtml, ['test'])">


          <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[

                              import flash.display.Shape;

                              import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
                              import mx.core.UIComponent;
                              import mx.events.FlexEvent;

                              import spark.components.*;
                              import spark.components.supportClasses.StyleableTextField;
                              import spark.primitives.Rect;


                              public var mainWrapper:VGroup = new VGroup();
                              public var mainContainer:HGroup = new HGroup();

                              //Icon Item Renderer
                              public var iconItemWrapper:HGroup = new HGroup();
                              public var iconItemImage:Image = new Image();
                              /* Text elements */
                              public var iconItemTextGroup:VGroup = new VGroup();
                              public var iconItemLabel:Label = new Label();
                              public var iconItemHtmlMessagex:TextArea = new TextArea();
                              /* Star rating */
                              public var iconItemRaterGroup:HGroup = new HGroup();
                              public var iconItemRater:*;

                              //Decorator
                              public var decoratorGroup:VGroup = new VGroup();
                              public var decoratorText:Label = new Label();
                              public var counterGroup:Rect = new Rect();
                              public var counterText:Label = new Label();
                              public var decoratorImage:Image = new Image();

                              //Icon Item Borders
                              public var iconItemTopBorder:Rect = new Rect();
                              public var iconItemBottomBorder:Rect = new Rect();
                              public var iconItemBackground:Rect = new Rect();

                              import flash.display.Graphics;
                              import mx.graphics.LinearGradient;
                              import mx.graphics.GradientEntry;

                              protected function drawHeader():void
                              {
                                        decoratorText.setStyle("fontFamily","Roboto");
                                        decoratorText.setStyle("fontSize","16");
                                        decoratorText.setStyle("fontWeight","bold");
                                        decoratorText.setStyle("color","#ffffff");
                                        decoratorText.setStyle("paddingRight","5");
                                        decoratorText.setStyle("paddingTop","5");
                                        decoratorText.setStyle("paddingLeft","5");
                                        decoratorText.setStyle("paddingBottom","5");
                                        decoratorText.text = data.Location
                                        addElement(decoratorText);

                              }

                              protected function renderIconItem():void
                              {

                                        //main wrapper
                                        iconItemWrapper.paddingBottom=5;
                                        iconItemWrapper.paddingTop=5;
                                        iconItemWrapper.paddingLeft=5;
                                        iconItemWrapper.verticalAlign="top";


                                        addElement(iconItemWrapper);



                                        //icon
                                        iconItemImage.source = data.Image;

                                        if(iconItemImage.sourceWidth > 64){
                                                  iconItemImage.width = 64;
                                                  iconItemImage.height = 64;
                                        }else{
                                                  iconItemImage.width = iconItemImage.sourceWidth;
                                                  iconItemImage.height = iconItemImage.sourceHeight;
                                        }

                                        iconItemImage.sourceWidth
                                        iconItemWrapper.addElement(iconItemImage);

                                        iconItemTextGroup.gap = 0;
                                        iconItemTextGroup.paddingBottom=0;
                                        iconItemTextGroup.paddingTop=0;
                                        iconItemTextGroup.verticalAlign="top";
                                        iconItemWrapper.addElement(iconItemTextGroup);

                                        //title
                                        iconItemLabel.setStyle("fontFamily","Roboto");
                                        iconItemLabel.setStyle("fontWeight","bold");
                                        iconItemLabel.setStyle("color","#000000");
                                        iconItemLabel.setStyle("fontSize","16");
                                        iconItemLabel.setStyle("paddingRight","0");
                                        iconItemLabel.setStyle("paddingTop","0");
                                        iconItemLabel.setStyle("paddingLeft","0");
                                        iconItemLabel.setStyle("paddingBottom","0");
                                        iconItemLabel.text = data.Product;
                                        iconItemTextGroup.addElement(iconItemLabel);

                                        //message
                                        iconItemHtmlMessagex.focusEnabled = false;
                                        iconItemHtmlMessagex.selectable = false;
                                        iconItemHtmlMessagex.setStyle("paddingLeft","0");
                                        iconItemHtmlMessagex.setStyle("paddingTop","0");
                                        iconItemHtmlMessagex.setStyle("borderVisible","false");
                                        iconItemHtmlMessagex.setStyle("contentBackgroundAlpha","0");
                                        iconItemTextGroup.addElement(iconItemHtmlMessagex);
                                        renderMessageText();

                                        //iconItemRaterGroup
                                        //iconItemRaterGroup.paddingTop=0;
                                        //iconItemRaterGroup.verticalAlign="bottom";
                                        //iconItemTextGroup.addElement(iconItemRaterGroup);

                                        //decoratorGroup
                                        decoratorGroup.paddingTop=10;
                                        decoratorGroup.verticalAlign="bottom";
                                        iconItemWrapper.addElement(decoratorGroup);

                                        //decoratorText
                                        decoratorText.setStyle("fontFamily","Roboto");
                                        decoratorText.setStyle("fontSize","12");
                                        decoratorText.setStyle("fontWeight","bold");
                                        decoratorText.setStyle("color","#777777");
                                        decoratorText.setStyle("paddingRight","0");
                                        decoratorText.setStyle("paddingTop","0");
                                        decoratorText.setStyle("paddingLeft","0");
                                        decoratorText.setStyle("paddingBottom","0");
                                        decoratorText.text = data.Location
                                        decoratorGroup.addElement(decoratorText);



                                        //decoratorImage
                                        decoratorImage.width = 32;
                                        decoratorImage.height = 32;
                                        decoratorImage.source = "recycle-icon.png";
                                        decoratorImage.sourceHeight
                                        decoratorImage.sourceWidth
                                        decoratorGroup.addElement(decoratorImage);

                              }
                              public var myStyleSheet:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();

                              private function renderMessageText():void {

                                        var styles:String = "p{ font-size: 11px; }
                                                                       a{ font-size: 11px; color: #0C81F5; text-decoration: underline; }
                                                                       a:hover { color: #CCDEF0; text-decoration: underline; }";

                                        myStyleSheet.parseCSS(styles);
                                        StyleableTextField(iconItemHtmlMessagex.textDisplay).htmlText = data.Description2;

                              }

                              public function renderHtml(varx:String):void{
                                        setTimeout(renderHtmlTimeout, 1);
                              }

                              public function renderHtmlTimeout():void{
                                        StyleableTextField(iconItemHtmlMessagex.textDisplay).styleSheet = myStyleSheet;

                              }

                              override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
                              {
                                        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

                                                  renderIconItem();
                                                  this.graphics.clear();
                                                  this.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, [0xffffff,0xefefef], [1,1], [0,255],verticalGradientMatrix(0,0,unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight));
                                                  this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

                              }

                    ]]>
          </fx:Script>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

and view1.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                    creationComplete="ini();">
          <fx:Declarations>
                    <s:HTTPService id="xmlDataResource" url="properties.xml"  
                                                     result="xmlDatasource = xmlDataResource.lastResult.slist.products"/>
          </fx:Declarations>
          <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                              import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

                              [Bindable]
                              public var xmlDatasource:ArrayCollection;

                              public function ini():void{

                                        xmlDataResource.send();

                              }


                    ]]>
          </fx:Script>


          <s:List id="categoryList" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" borderAlpha="0.5"
                              itemRenderer="htmlRenderer"
                              dataProvider="{xmlDatasource}">
          </s:List>


</s:View>
```

The problem is that when the list loads data, only list items in the view port are rendered and the rest of the information is hidden.
Any help as im in the verge of getting a breakthrough in flex mobile.

below is the screen shot

thank

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the rest is not hidden, it is simply not there :)

The concept of the `List`-based classes/components in Flex is, the only the visible data is assigned and rendered. If e.g. your list has the height to display 8 items, then it will create 10 items and reuse them. If you scroll up and an items leaves the viewport, it is placed at the bottom of the list and gets new data.

If you want to create all objects and scroll them, try wrapping a `VGroup` inside a `Scroller`.

Comment: If I use the 'native' IconTemRenderer as a renderer, all the information in the data is displayed in the List. My custom renderer does not seem to display all list items as in the IconTemRenderer.  Am i missing something in making all list items visible on scrolling.